# Indy method HEAD takes forever if responce code is not good (200)

Tags: delphi, timeout, indy, head

I am using INDY 10 with Delphi 2010 and I noticed some drawback when using method HEAD in IdHTTP component.

I want to check whether a particular file is ready for download. So I am using HEAD instead of GET to check if it's 404 or 200. The problem is that if the file is inexistent the method head takes at least couple of seconds until timeout occurs.

```
var
 LHTTP:TIdHTTP;
begin
 LHTTP:=TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
 try
  LHTTP.Head('http://www.google.com/inexistent');
```

this takes at least 15 seconds, while when I use GET method, it takes miliseconds to result in a exception 404.

EDIT: I found something in the source code:
It stucks at the line 1052 of IdHTTP.pas file:

```
IOHandler.ReadStream(LS, AResponse.ContentLength);
```

a couple of lines above there is a notice:

```
  // RLebeau 6/30/2006: DO NOT READ IF THE REQUEST IS HEAD!!!
  // The server is supposed to send a 'Content-Length' header
  // without sending the actual data...
```

I think something is wrong here ;-)

Comment: Try Indy 10.6 to see if the error has been fixed. (Delphi 2010 is quite old.)

Comment: thanks, update helped me with this issue.